# Failed opening required Slim/Slim.php

Tags: php, angularjs, slim

Hi I am new in slim framework and using Slim framework in backend and using AngularJS in client, when load data from server this following error show:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Slim/slim.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/ngelgir0/public_html/api/index.php on line 3

Here is my folder structure:

```
public_html/
    - api
    + Slim
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

[image]

And here is the first few lines in `index.php`:

```php
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new Slim();

// endpoints related with FeedbackFormsResource
$app->get('/feedbacks', 'getFeedbackForms');
$app->get('/feedbacks/:id', 'getFeedbackFormsById');
$app->get('/feedbacks/search/:query', 'findFeedbackForm');
$app->post('/feedbacks/', 'addFeedbackForm');
$app->put('/feedbacks/:id', 'updateFeedbackForm');
$app->delete('/feedbacks/:id', 'deleteFeedbackForm');
```

And this is what I have for `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: put .htaccess file outside api directory (in public_html/)

Comment: i did but not work  and same error show

Comment: please help me i try not work

Comment: please check the file name require 'Slim/Slim.php'; in the screenshot i could see the file name looks "slim.php" it should be "Slim.php"

Comment: tanks for answer Vigikaran but name is true before cheked name

Comment: tanks very nice answer

Comment: when chek again name is slim.php and for reason upload second file

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot says that the error is located in `api/index.php`.
If you have `require Slim/slim.php` inside that index.php that Slim folder must be inside `api`.

To fix that do a

```
require '../Slim/Slim.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a `define` which references your file root for future reference. If you ever need to include, you won't need to go up or down directories with the `../`.

```
define('FILE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__).'/');
require_once FILE_ROOT.'Slim/Slim.php';
```

to get the current directory and work with that you can use:

```
getcwd();
```